# vim-fugitive support for diff --color-words

Tags: filetype-tex, vimdiff, filetype-markdown, git, plugin-fugitive

I use `vim` and `git` primarily for editing prose documents in LaTeX or Markdown, not for coding. For this reason, my go-to `git diff` command is `git wdiff`, where the relevant part of `.gitconfig` reads

```
    wdiff = "diff --color-words='[^][<>()\\{},.;:?/|\\\\=+*&^%$#@!~`\"'\\''[:space:]]+|[][<>(){},.;:?/|\\\\=+*&^%$#@!~`\"'\\'']' --histogram"
```

(I got the regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759375/putting-regex-to-make-git-diff-split-words-at-punctuation-into-gitconfig-file/67762679#67762679).)

But right now when I use `vim-fugitive` to run `:Git wdiff`, I get garbled output with some sort ASCII encoding for the colors instead of the actual colors themselves, for example:

```
^[[1mdiff --git a/interview.md b/interview.md^[[m
^[[1mindex a464fb2..fb379fc 100644^[[m
^[[1m--- a/interview.md^[[m
^[[1m+++ b/interview.md^[[m
^[[36m@@ -129,4 +129,4 @@^[[m ^[[mand instituted several different online^[[m
seminars. ^[[m

Some prose ^[[32mwith some more verbiage inserted^[[m that ends here.
```

The `:Git diff` command works fine and outputs colored `diff` output as expected.

How can I get `fugitive` to output `diff --color-words` properly? (Or better yet, how can I get it to do so with the customized regex printed above?)

Comment: fugitive don't recognize ascii color codes (nor should it, a/c unix philosohpy). You should look for [questions like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes) instead. I myself would simply not use the color codes and let fugitive decide the colors based on the `+` and `-` signs. Is there any particular reason you disabled the signs? And is enabling them (with a new alias that don't use color codes) for vim-fugitive out of the question? Cause if not, then the solution is pretty simple.

Comment: Oh, right. You don't want noise (of the symbols). Yeah then you should definitely use a plugin for handling ascii color codes.

Comment: I'd just use `:term git wdiff %` (or make a custom command if it's a regular/common use-case).

Comment: I'd rather not use `:term` commands if possible.

Comment: That is, I'm hoping for a solution that will use `vim-fugitive` in just the same way as `:Git diff`, with the only difference being the `--color-words` formatting of the output (which, as you say, indicates changes not linewise with `+` and `-` but rather word-wise with nothing but the color coding to distinguish deletions and additions from text that is unchanged).

Comment: I've also submitted [a feature request](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/2036) on the `vim-fugitive` github page, in case that is a better forum for my query.

Comment: As Tim Pope pointed out [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/2036#issuecomment-1215995042), the package *does* support the `--word-diff` option (`:Git diff --word-diff`), which is pretty close. So I'll use that for now.